# How to create anchor text links in facebook posts

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

How can I create a text link with anchor text in a facebook fanpage post?
It works because I have seen many posts containing such links, even in comments.

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">Anchor Text</a>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#links

Comment: that is for sharing links from your website. I need to enter anchor text link from my browser when I post a photo, add a link in the description.

Comment: In that case, Facebook should automatically detect and wrap your url in html, provided it is a proper absolute URL.

Comment: I need an anchor text for the link, instead of the normal url.

Comment: For normal posts, you can not use any HTML, and therefor also not give link texts for the “naked” URLs that may be contained in the message and get transformed to clickable links automatically by Facebook. Whatever you have seen somewhere must have been something else. (“Notes” maybe? In those you can use some basic HTML – but this is only shown in the detail view of the note; showing up in news feed notes are stripped of any HTML and only the pure text content is shown.)

Answer (score 5):

Two scenarios:

Posts: Not possible. Can only have very basic HTML formatting: bold, italic, strike, underline.

[Notes](https://www.facebook.com/help/488014787881885/): Possible. Quite a number of HTML allowed. Access by typing "My Notes" into the search field. Click. Edit your note and publish it as if it was a Post.

Comment: Note that this may not work as expected since the links are not displayed until the user clicks to open up the note. There are no links in the feed, which is probably what most people want.

Answer (score -6):

Most easy solution with photo tutorial 
see there >> 
[How to Create Hyperlinks to Anchor Text on Facebook](http://www.araddho.com/how-to-create-hyperlinks-to-anchor-text-on-facebook/)

Comment: Please include the actual answer in your answer. Imagine the blog would be offline - the answer would be lost!

Comment: It suggests using [Notes](https://www.facebook.com/notes) instead of usual posts. Basically the same answer as the one by isync.